# How to call notifydatasetchanged of inner listview?

Tags: android, listview

Am using a listview inside another listview when i click a button on listview i have to add items to inner listview. How to call notifydatasetchanged of inner listview adapter.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.homeinnernew1, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.lv = (ListView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            holder.ed_Comment=(EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edComment);
                        holder.btnSend=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        ct=new ArrayList<Comment>();
        for(int j=0;j<listComment.size();j++){
            Comment objComment=listComment.get(j);                              
            ct.add(objComment);
        }
        myadapter = new CommentListAdapter(context,ct,a);
        holder.lv.setAdapter(n);

        holder.btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text=edText.getText().toString();
                Comment objComment=new Comment("1", "2", "1", "sadsa,"text",sadsa") ;
                commentList.add(objComment);
                myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Comment: post your code, why you don't use Expandable listView?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() belongs to the adapter, as you should have 2 separate adapters for two different listviews simply call yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() or yourOtherAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). P.S. you really shouldn't nest two listviews, how does scrolling work in this case ?

Comment: is it possible without expandable listview?

Comment: yes scrolling works fine

Comment: you send `ct` to your adapter then you add new object in `commentList`, how you want `myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` work for you? you need change `ct` or any object that you send to adapter class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to notify both adapters, so that the outer adapter knows that it needs to refresh its views. You may even need notify the outer adapter that its data set is invalidated.